# Get number of rows of a stored procedure without loop

Tags: c#, razor

Using c# how can I get the number of rows of the output of a stored procedure? I am trying something without loop and without using COUNT(*) in the database. basically something like:

`db.Query("storedProcedure").count()`

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch the data into a `DataSet`, you can then do something like:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx

`.Tables[0]` indicates the first set of results returned by your query (if you happen to have multiple `SELECT` statements in your stored procedure). Otherwise it's simply referring to the results of your only `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the stored procedure to output rows total along with its usual output (Microsoft SQL server syntax)

```
create proc dbo.My_Test
  @rows int out
as

-- preparing test data - ignore that
declare @tmp table(id int)
insert into @tmp values(1)
insert into @tmp values(2)

select * from @tmp

select @rows = @@rowcount
```

If you stored procedure already exists and it doesnt' play with "set nocount on"; you can retrieve counts like:

```
create proc dbo.My_Test
as
-- preparing test data - ignore that
declare @tmp table(id int)
insert into @tmp values(1)
insert into @tmp values(2)

select * from @tmp
```

and call the sp like:

```
declare @rows int
exec dbo.My_Test
select @rows = @@rowcount
-- @rows = 2
```

Comment: this is my main point. I am trying to keep the procedure as it is. I dont want to go around modifying every procedure. I want to try for a way to get the no. of rows from an existing procedure.